# Is it possible to enable mercurial push over http and keep using SSL keys for authentication?

Tags: mercurial

Currently we are using `http://` only for readonly access and devs have to change the repository adress to use `ssh://hguser@...` in order to be able to push.

Is it possible to enable push and still identify users based on SSL keys. Alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial provides for two default paths in configuration files.  You can define a `default-push` path that is used for push operations while `default` is used for pull operations.  So, in your repository `.hg/hgrc` file, you can add something like:

```
[paths]
default = http://...
default-push = ssh://...
```

See `hg help paths` for more info.

Comment: Is it possible to publish this information on the server side, so people do not have to configure these themselves?

Comment: An hgrc file is not normally version-controlled within a repository so it is not automatically downloaded.  But hg has a hierarchy of locations for searching for hgrc information: at the repo level, at the user level, within hg itself, etc.  See http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html for more info.

Comment: To summarize your last reply: **it is impossible to define the default-push at the hg server side**, so each user has to play with his `.hg` file in order to make it work.

Comment: hg does not have a concept of a server in, say, the `svn` sense so it is better to not think in those terms. Each hg repo is a full, standalone repo. hg can determine that two repos have a common ancestry and it can compute the difference between two repos and allow you to incorporate the differences from one repo to another. Anything beyond that is a matter of policy about how you use your various repos; from hg's perspective all repos are equal. Setting up the proper .hg/hgrc file is a one-time operation when a repo is cloned. You could add a sample file in the repo for users to copy.

Comment: Thanks Ned, clearly simplicity was not something that hg designers considered. Try to see the big picture, hundreds of devs, tens of repositories,... even the smallest additional setup step is a productivity killer.

Comment: DVCS's like hg or git are in many ways inherently much more flexible than an client-server system like svn and with that flexibility comes more complexity in some aspects.  There is no way for hg to know in general what paths are appropriate for any repo.  OTOH, the difference between documenting one specific command (`hg clone http:/some/path myrepo`) to set up a dev environment versus a couple of commands seems pretty minimal in the long run (`hg clone http://some/path myrepo; cd myrepo; cp COPYME_TO_.hg/hgrc`).

Answer (score 0):

@votingmeisfree, the [projrc extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ProjrcExtension) may help you take care of this configuration without each developer having to.